# Iterating over date range between two pandas dataframes for category count

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe(df1 and df2):

df1 has 12 columns, where a1, a2, ..., a9 are empty columns. Below is a sample for df1:

```
Stock Start_Date          End_Date        a1 a2 a3 a4 .... a9
A   09-12-2015 20:04    10-12-2015 23:04                
B   09-12-2015 10:04    09-12-2015 20:14                
A   11-12-2015 00:22    11-12-2015 08:04                
C   08-12-2015 06:56    10-12-2015 20:54
```

df2 has 4 columns. Below is a sample:

```
Stock   date_time     Opening   closing
A   09-12-2015 21:24    144.3   10
A   09-12-2015 21:27    225.51  24
B   09-12-2015 10:20    134.42  11
A   09-12-2015 20:04    231.22  17
B   09-12-2015 10:24    399.55  32
A   09-12-2015 20:04    246.77  21
B   09-12-2015 14:22    76.23   8
C   08-12-2015 09:44    232.22  15
C   09-12-2015 20:04    222.91  12
A   11-12-2015 02:06    93.21   7
B   09-12-2015 20:04    211.36  26
C   09-12-2015 20:04    111.21  8
```

Now, I would want the output to be like this, df1:

```
Stock   Start_Date       End_Date          a1   a2  a3  a4 ....a9
A   09-12-2015 20:04    10-12-2015 23:04    0   2   2   0      0
B   09-12-2015 10:04    09-12-2015 20:14    1   1   2   0      0
A   11-12-2015 00:22    11-12-2015 08:04    1   0   0   0      0
C   08-12-2015 06:56    10-12-2015 20:54    0   0   0   1      0
```

i.e for each Stock, Start_Date & End_Date combination of df1, the result should have count of each category in that date-time range from df2.

Here in final output, a1 = count[opening(0-100)&closing(0-10)], a2 = count[opening(101-200)&closing(11-20)], a3 = count[opening(201-400)&closing(21-50)], a4 = count[opening(0-100)&closing(11-20)] and so on, all 9 combinations.

I've the R code for this but works poorly for a bigger data set.Can anybody help me with how to do this in python/pandas. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution, where I remove empty columns of `df1`, but it works with them too:

```
#merge dataframes by Stock, select datetimes between start and end
df = df1.merge(df2,on='Stock', how='left')
df = df[(df.date_time >= df.Start_Date) & (df.date_time <= df.End_Date)]
#remove column date_time
df = df.drop(['date_time'], axis=1)
print df
#   Stock          Start_Date            End_Date  Opening  closing
#0      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   144.30       10
#1      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   225.51       24
#2      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   231.22       17
#3      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   246.77       21
#5      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   134.42       11
#6      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   399.55       32
#7      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00    76.23        8
#8      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   211.36       26
#13     A 2015-11-12 00:22:00 2015-11-12 08:04:00    93.21        7
#14     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   232.22       15
#15     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   222.91       12
#16     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   111.21        8

#values to new columns by conditions - cast boolean to integers
df['a1'] = ((df.Opening.between(0,100)) & (df.closing.between(0,10))).astype(int)
df['a2'] = ((df.Opening.between(100,200)) & (df.closing.between(11,20))).astype(int)
#add other columns like a1 and a2
print df
#   Stock          Start_Date            End_Date  Opening  closing  a1  a2
#0      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   144.30       10   0   0
#1      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   225.51       24   0   0
#2      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   231.22       17   0   0
#3      A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   246.77       21   0   0
#5      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   134.42       11   0   1
#6      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   399.55       32   0   0
#7      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00    76.23        8   1   0
#8      B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   211.36       26   0   0
#13     A 2015-11-12 00:22:00 2015-11-12 08:04:00    93.21        7   1   0
#14     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   232.22       15   0   0
#15     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   222.91       12   0   0
#16     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   111.21        8   0   0

#groupby and sum rows
df= df.groupby(['Stock', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date']).sum()
df = df.drop(['Opening', 'closing'], axis=1)
print df.reset_index()
#  Stock          Start_Date            End_Date  a1  a2
#0     A 2015-09-12 20:04:00 2015-10-12 23:04:00   0   0
#1     A 2015-11-12 00:22:00 2015-11-12 08:04:00   1   0
#2     B 2015-09-12 10:04:00 2015-09-12 20:14:00   1   1
#3     C 2015-08-12 06:56:00 2015-10-12 20:54:00   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly fine. just one more thing, what if I've another column(double or float) in df1. Is it possible to get that in the final output by changing the "how" in merge?

Comment: I think `on` in function `merge` is for matching - better example with pictures is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). `df = df1.merge(df2,on='Stock', how='left')` is same as `df = pd.merge(df1, df2,on='Stock', how='left')` .

Comment: Thanks, help appreciated. Works similar to merge function in R. Is there a way to add another column(with values) present in df1 in the final output() ?

Comment: Hmmm, I think if you merge `df1` and `df2` by `Stock`, you get all other columns from df1, so another columns too. Try it.